# Post mutation to graphql with axios

Tags: graphql, axios

This query in `grahiql` works:

```
mutation {
  addSkill(id:"5",name:"Javascript",level:1,type:"frontend") {
    status
    id
    name
    level
    type
  }
}
```

What is the equivalent to post with `axios`?

I've tried this, but keep getting a `400` request response.

> {"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Unterminated string.","locations":[{"line":3,"column":82}]}]}

This is what I tried:

```
axios
  .post(config.apiendpoint, {
    query: `
      mutation addSkill($id:String!, $name:String!, $level:Float!, $type:String!) {
        mutation addSkill(id:$id, name:$name", level:$level, type:$type) { 
          status
          id
          name
          level
          type
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: String(id),
      name: this.form.name,
      level: this.form.level,
      type: this.form.type,
    },
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Am sure the values in the `variables` are of the right `type` and is not empty too.

Answer (score 25):

I would avoid including variables directly in the query like this, because that way you have to constantly adjust how your variables fit into the template literal, like stringifying stuff and adding quotes.

Use `graphql` `print` to do it for you!

Try this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { print } from 'graphql';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const ADD_SKILL = gql`
mutation addSkill($id:String!, $name:String!, $level:Float!, $type:String!) {
  addSkill(id:$id, name:$name, level:$level, type:$type) { 
    status
    id
    name
    level
    type
  }
}
`

axios.post(config.apiendpoint, {
  query: print(ADD_SKILL),
  variables: {
    id: String(id),
    name: this.form.name,
    level: parseFloat(this.form.level),
    type: this.form.type,
  },
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 9):

Found the problem.

1. Remove the extra `mutation`
2. Rmove the extra `"` after `$name`

*Update - a cleaner version*:

```
axios
.post(config.apiendpoint, {
  query: `mutation {
      addSkill(id:"${id}", name:"${this.form.name}", level:${parseFloat(this.form.level)}, type:"${this.form.type}") {
        status
        id
        name
        level
        type
      }
    }
  `,
}).then().catch()
```

Here's the working request for reference.

```
axios
.post(config.apiendpoint, {
  query: `
    mutation addSkill($id:String!, $name:String!, $level:Float!, $type:String!) {
      addSkill(id:$id, name:$name, level:$level, type:$type) { 
        status
        id
        name
        level
        type
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    id: String(id),
    name: this.form.name,
    level: parseFloat(this.form.level),
    type: this.form.type,
  },
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
const mutation = `
    mutation InventoryBulkAdjustQuantitiesAtLocationMutation($inventoryItemAdjustments: [InventoryAdjustItemInput!]!) {
        inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation(inventoryItemAdjustments: $inventoryItemAdjustments, locationId: "${req.body.locationId}") {
            inventoryLevels {
                id
                available
                incoming
                item {
                    id
                    sku
                }
                location {
                    id
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
const query: any = {
    query: mutation,
    variables: {
        "inventoryItemAdjustments": req.body.variables
    }
}
const url = process.env.SHOPIFY_URL_DOMAIN + process.env.END_POINT
const resp = await axios.post(url,
    (isMutation ? JSON.stringify(query) : query),
    {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': (isMutation ? 'application/json' : 'application/graphql' ),
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': process?.env?.SHOPIFY_API_TOKEN,
    }
})
```