# Calling graphQL server mutation to axios url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, axios

I am currently using GraphQL Server and axios for client side. 
I would like to know how to call this graphQL to my axios

```
mutation {
 createUser(email: "hello@gmail.com") {
   email
 }
}
```

How can I call it like this?

```
const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/public?query={users{email}');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post mutation to graphql with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630137/post-mutation-to-graphql-with-axios)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `post` method to send your query/mutation to the GraphQL server:

```
axios({
  // Of course the url should be where your actual GraphQL server is.
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
      query: `
        mutation createUser($email: email){
            createUser(email: $email) {
               email
            }
        }`,
     variables: {
        email: "hello@gmail.com"
     }
  }
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data)
});
```

Comment: @Overwatch "It's not working" is not really helpful when it comes to debugging. Could you provide more information? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: It was just a mistake, yeah it's working properly i just a bit confused in the query part but it's now working. Thanks.