# Post data to a graphql server with request-promise

Tags: graphql, request-promise

I'm using the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) library to make http request to a graphql server. To achieve a query, I'm doing this:

```
const query = `
    {
    user(id:"123173361311") {
      _id
      name
      email
    }
  }
`

const options = {
  uri: "http://localhost:5000/graphql",
  qs: { query },
  json: true
}

return await request(options)
```

The above code is working fine. However I'm confused about how to go about a mutation since I need to specify both the actual mutation and the inputData like this:

```
// Input
{
   name: "lomse"
   email: "lomse@lomse.com"
}

const mutation = `
   mutation addUser($input: AddUserInput!){
      addUser(input: $input) {
          _id
          name
          email
      }
   }
`

const option = {
    uri: "http://localhost:5000/graphql",
    formData: {mutation},
    json: true,
    // how to pass the actual data input
}

request.post(option)
```

Or is it that the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) library isn't designed for this use case?

Comment: query can contain variables, too ... inspect browser network requests for details in some graphiql playground

Comment: Interestingly, the network tab isn't recording any request for mutations

Comment: socket communication can be used

Comment: search for `post mutation`, f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636430/6124657

Comment: The research is showing how to perform a mutation from the frontend, which is not what I'm trying to accomplish. In my case, I have two servers that need to communicate with each other

Comment: just check used structures/parameters and adapt to your needs

Comment: https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request seems to do what I was looking for. Thanks for the time @xadm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `body`, not `formData`. Your body should consist of three properties:

- `query`: The GraphQL document you're sending. Even if the operation is a mutation, the property is still named query.
- `variables`: A map of your variable values serialized as a JSON object. Only required if your operation utilized variables.
- `operationName`: Specifies which operation to execute. Only required if your document included multiple operations.

```
request.post({
  uri : '...',
  json: true,
  body: {
    query: 'mutation { ... }',
    variables: {
      input: {
        name: '...',
        email: '...',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Is this mentioned in their documentation? Where did you get this information from?

Comment: Since GraphQL is transport-agnostic, the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/) itself does not specify how HTTP requests should be handled. The above is mostly just convention. The official site [does mention it though](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request).

Comment: I must have missed that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request) library seems to do what I needed the request-promise library to do.

```
import { request } from 'graphql-request'

const variables = {
   name: "lomse",
   email: "lomse@lomse.com"
}

const mutation = `
   mutation addUser($input: AddUserInput!){
      addUser(input: $input) {
          _id
          name
          email
      }
   }
`

response = await request(uri, mutation, {input: variables})
```